# I have an empty object from console (req.body)

Tags: mongodb, body-parser

Can someone help me . I have already tried to use the answers given in the similar project but i didn't be able to fix my problem .Thanks for help

I have many files :

#### Controllers file : The error occurs here :

EmployeeControllers.js :

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('../models/employee.model');
const router = express.Router();
let Employee = mongoose.model('Employee');
router.get('/', (req,res)=>{
  res.render('employee/addOrEdit',{
    viewTitle: "Insert Employee"
  });
});
router.post('/', (req,res)=> {
let employee = new Employee();
employee.fullName = req.body.fullName;
employee.email = req.body.email;
employee.mobile = req.body.mobile;
employee.city = req.body.city;
employee.save((err) => {
  if(!err){ res.redirect('employee/list') }
  else{console.log('Error during record insertion : '+err ) }
})
console.log(typeof req.body); // i try to look at the type 
console.log(req.body);
});
router.get('/list', (req,res)=>{
  res.json('Simple Test')
});
module.exports = router;
```

Output after submitting the form :
{}.

Here is the rest of the file , I know it's too much :

Index.js:

```
require('./models/db') ;
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const employeeController = require('./controllers/employeeControllers');
var app = express();
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false});
app.use(urlencodedParser);
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/employee', employeeController);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/views/') );
app.engine('hbs', exphbs({extname:'hbs', defaultLayout: 'mainLayout', layoutsDir:__dirname + '/views/layouts/'}));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.listen(3000, () =>{
console.log('Express server stard at port : 3000');
});
```

#### Models files : Mongoose connection and mongoose Schema

db.js :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/EmployeeDB', {useNewUrlParser: true},(err)=>{
if(!err){console.log('Connection Succceeded')}
else{console.log('Connection not found')}
});
require('./employee.model');
```

Employee.model.js :

```
enter code here 

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var employeeSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
fullName:{type: String },
email : {type: String },
mobile : {type: String },
city : {type: String }
});
let Employee = module.exports = mongoose.model('Employee', employeeSchema)
```

#### Views folders :

Layout folder :

- mainLayout.hbs :

  Node and Express Crash Cours       {{{body}}}

Employe : addOrEdit.hbs

```
<h3>{{viewTitle}} </h3> <form action="/employee" method="post" > <div class="form-group"> <label >Full Name</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" class="fullName" placeholder="Full Name"> </div> <div class="form-group"> <label>Email</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" class="email" placeholder="email"> </div> <div class="form-row"> <div class="form-group col-md-6"> <label >Mobile</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" class="mobile" placeholder="mobile"> </div> <div class="form-group col-md-6"> <label >City</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" class="city" placeholder="city"> </div> </div> <div class="form-group"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-database"></i> Submit</button> </div> </form>
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? I see a lot of code but I don’t know what you are trying to do; what are you expecting that you aren’t seeing?

Comment: @C.Peck : I would like to get the data in my database througth the post request . But in my console i have an empty object instead of retrieving the email, mobile and city from the form .Hope that you understand the issue now. Thanks for your help